# Conflict while rendering nested components with React Router 4

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, material-ui, react-router-v4

I have a problem with my routing using React Router 4. When using "nested" routes, one of the top routes renders a component that is matching the route but I don't want it to be rendered. I'll put the important pieces of code here and will explain what I'm trying to achieve. Here is my main/top level routing, I've removed some lines of code that are irrelevant to the issue:

This is my `App.js` file:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Route} from 'react-router-dom';
import {withRouter} from 'react-router';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps} from './selector';
import HomeView from './packages/home-view';
import HardwareView from './packages/hardware-view';
import HardwareAddView from './packages/hardware-add-view';
import HardwareTypesAddView from './packages/hardware-types-add-view';

class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="App">
                <main>
                    <Route exact path="/" component={HomeView} />
                    <Route path="/hardware" component={HardwareView} />
                    <Route exact path="/hardware/add" component={HardwareAddView} />
                    <Route exact path="/hardware/types/add" component={HardwareTypesAddView} />
                </main>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(App));
```

`HomeView` component only renders an empty `<div/>` for the moment.

Now lets move into the `HardwareView` component. Inside this component I am rendering a `<Tabs/>` component from material-ui. This `<Tabs/>` component will have 2 tabs, and each of those tabs will have its own component as content. So to illustrate, It can be seen as this:

```
App.js (div.App -> main) 
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                                                                          |
|     hardware-view.js (Tabs component)                                    |
|    +---------------------------------------------------------------+     |
|    |              Hardware          |        Hardware Types        |     |       
|    |       (Link to="/hardware")    | (Link to="/hardware/types")  |     |
|    +---------------------------------------------------------------+     |
|    |  Tab Content:                                                 |     |
|    |                                                               |     |
|    | A table that is served only when the exact path is "/hardware"|     |
|    | if the Hardware tab is selected. Or the content from          |     |
|    | "/hardware/types" if the Hardware Types tab is selected       |     |
|    |                                                               |     |
|    | - HardwareList for "/hardware"                                |     |
|    | - HardwareTypesList for "/hardware/types"                     |     |
|    +---------------------------------------------------------------+     |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Both of the Tab Content components (HardwareList or HardwareTypesList) that gets rendered when any tab is selected, will include a link button that will navigate to either `/hardware/add` or `/hardware/types/add`. This is were the problem comes in. When I navigate to either `/hardware/add` or `/hardware/types/add`, I want to render a complete new view without the `<Tabs/>` component, but that is not possible since the route `<Route path="/hardware" component={HardwareView} />` is matching `/hardware/add` or `/hardware/types/add` because it doesn't have the `exact` property.

Here is my `packages/hardware-view/index.js` file that contains the `HardwareView` component:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import Paper from 'material-ui/Paper';
import {Tabs, Tab} from 'material-ui/Tabs';
import {Route, Link} from 'react-router-dom';
import HardwareList from '../hardware-list';
import HardwareTypesList from '../hardware-types-list';


export default class HardwareView extends Component {
    render() {
        const {location} = this.props;
        const {pathname} = location;

        return (
            <div className="hardware-view-component">
                <Paper zDepth={2}>
                    <Tabs value={pathname}>
                        <Tab label="Hardware" containerElement={<Link to="/hardware" />} value="/hardware">
                            <div className="tab-content">
                                <Route exact path="/hardware" component={HardwareList} />
                            </div>
                        </Tab>
                        <Tab label="Hardware Types" containerElement={<Link to="/hardware/types" />} value="/hardware/types">
                            <div className="tab-content">
                                <Route exact path="/hardware/types" component={HardwareTypesList} />
                            </div>
                        </Tab>
                    </Tabs>
                </Paper>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

I've tried using the Layouts approach as [described here](https://themeteorchef.com/tutorials/getting-started-with-react-router-v4) but had no luck. I know I may be overthinking this and there is a more clean approach for this. Any suggestions or guide on how to achieve what I'm looking for?

**TLDR**;
Trying to render a route inside a route, but because of the paths for the routes, the base path of the URL is rendering the top level component. For example `/foo` renders "Component A", `/foo/bar` renders "Component A" and has "Component B" inside the A, but I want for `/foo/bar/baz` to render ONLY "Component C" and It's rendering "Component A" and "Component C".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Switch` renders the first child `<Route>` or `<Redirect>` that matches the location ([source: docs](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Switch))

```
<Switch>
  <Route exact path="/" component={HomeView} />
  <Route exact path="/hardware/add" component={HardwareAddView} />
  <Route exact path="/hardware/types/add" component={HardwareTypesAddView} />
  <Route path="/hardware" component={HardwareView} />
</Switch>
```

Comment: This did not solve the issue. The Tab component is still rendered when navigating to `/hardware/add` or `/hardware/types/add`

Comment: The order of the routes inside `Switch` matter, as `Switch` will display the first matching route only. Did you try the order from my response?

Comment: Thanks Karthik Ravichandran, you are right, I wasn't considering the order of the routes. Now that the order is set, it solved the issue